# Is there a more performance friendly way to iterate through images for an animation than using an imageIcon array in Java?

Tags: java, image, swing, animation, paintcomponent

I'm Trying to Animate a seagull image on a JPanel for a game I'm building. The animation works great, it looks how I want it to, but when I click the play button to switch cards to the next JPanel, (There is a play button controlled by the JFrame containing this panel that changes the card to another JPanel, this lags when the animation is going) it lags when the animation is running. Is there a more performance friendly way to run my animation than by looping through an ImageIcon[] like I'm doing?

```
public class StartPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    
    Image gull;
    
    Timer timer;
    ImageIcon[] seagullAnimation = new ImageIcon[9];
    int counter = 0;
   

StartPanel(){
    seagullAnimation[0] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("gullBlink0.png"));
    //Here I add the rest of the images in the same fashion

    timer = new Timer(13, this);
    timer.start();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));

}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    //Iterates through the Gull Blink images and set the proper image
    if(counter >=8){
        counter = 0;
        timer.stop();
            try {    
                //Randomizes sleep times to make blink look natural
                Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 5000));
                timer.start();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
 
    } else {
        counter++;
    }
    gull = seagullAnimation[counter].getImage();

    g.drawImage(gull,10,-450, this);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
}}
```

Comment: Your drawing JPanel paintComponent method should paint the JPanel.  Period.  Timers or other code should be executed somewhere else.  If you provide a [mre] with all necessary images, you might get further help.  The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will show the correct way to construct a Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: Never _ever_ sleep on the EDT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the Lag. Removed the code that slept the Event Dispatch thread, which seemed to be causing the lag and used the timer to handle the pause between animations.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setGullFrame();
    gull = seagullAnimation[counter].getImage();
    g.drawImage(gull,10, -450, this);


public void setGullFrame(){
    
    if(counter >=8){
        counter = 0;
        timer.stop();
        timer.setInitialDelay((int) (Math.random() * 5000));
        timer.start();

    } else {
        counter++;
    }

}
```